Is the concatenation of these two FAs possible in a reasonable length?
I'm trying to concatenate the FAs for even-even and the language of words that contains at least one double a (aa).
The transition table for the concatenation seems to be getting very long. I've gotten 22 states so far which got me wondering if I was doing this correctly. If so then how many states would I be getting this way? It seems very difficult to create the final FA with so many states.
I'm sorry for the low-res images.



How are you constructing that table? The construction I know is: connect the accepting state of the first DFA to the start state of the second DFA with an epsilon transition, this makes an NFA, turn it back into a DFA in the standard way.

@harold I am indeed connecting the accepting state of the first DFA to the start state of the second DFA. In the first DFA with a as input to x2 it goes to the accepting state x1 and now besides it I've written y1 which is the initial state of the second DFA. This makes the new state Z4. I'm not really sure if this is the proper way to do it.
